# Change the Display Format of the NbDatePicker Date

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nebular

I want to change the display format of an NbDatePicker.

As the image below shows, the format is MONTH YEAR (AUGUST 2023). 
I want to change this to YEAR MONTH (2023 AUGUST). Is there a method to do that?

[image]